# Angular2 animation with async data array in bootstrap table

Tags: angular, animation, asynchronous, rxjs, bootstrap-table

I am trying to display async data table with angular animations. 
if new data inserted only new inserted data row should slide from left to right,
if data deleted from database deleted row needs to remove from left to right. 
I tried example from angular official site https://stackblitz.com/angular/vbqvbgqalxe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-list-enter-leave.component.ts
But I could not manage to apply it only some special rows.

Here is my code

client.component.ts

```
 people$: Observable<Person[]>;

 this.people$ = this.clientService.getDbData().map(res =>res);
```

client.component.html

```
  <tr *ngFor="let person of people$ | async " [style.color]="person.randomNum < person.second ? '#F61227':'#13F612'">
    <td style="width: 10%">{{person.Id}}</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">{{person.second}}</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">{{person.randomNum}}</td>
    <td style="width: 30%">{{person.name}}</td>
    <td style="width: 40%">{{person.surname}}</td>
  <tr>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? the code snippet shown here doesn't give any clue

Comment: @nkuma_12 I used the animations given in the link above. people$ array gets data continously, if some data changed (ad or delete in database) only affected data should display with animations. other rows should not be affect